# Как называется элемент архитектуры веб-приложения, который обрабатывает HTTP-запросы?

Tags: веб-программирование, архитектура, клиент-сервер, backend

"Сервер!" - так и хочется ответить на этот кажущийся глупым вопрос. Но если бы всё было так просто, я бы его на спрашивал на седьмом году в веб-разработке.

Хотя условное разделение веб-приложений на клиентскую и серверную часть популярно, архитектура современного веб-приложения не такая двоичная:

- База данных может быть на отдельном сервере
- Баз данных может быть несколько, и каждая на своём сервере
- Помимо "клиента" (которых, обычно сколь угодно много) и "сервера" (в свете первых двух пунктов уже довольно запутанного понятия), могут быть сторонние сервисы, такие логирование или аналитика, и у каждый свой сервер

Мне уже объяснили, что необходимо различать "сервер" как роль - источник и обработчик данных по отношению с клиенту, структуру которого клиент не обязан знать (концепция "чёрного ящика"); и как инфраструктуру этого самого чёрного ящика. Так вот, в этом вопросе меня больше интересует второе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итак, как называется помеченный тремя вопросительными знаками элемент системы, который принимает HTTP-запросы от клиентов и делает их первичную обработку? Мы не можем это просто так назвать "сервером", потому что серверов может быть сколь угодно умного, и у каждого - своя роль (обработка запросов с клиентской стороны, хранение данных, хранение файлов и т. д.). Например, при создании видео-хостинга рекомендуют обеспечить как минимум два сервера, один из которых возьмёт на себя отдачу только видеофайлов.

Термин HTTP-сервер тоже не описывает однозначно этот элемент. Допустим, тот самый сервер, который принимает запросы от клиентов, обменивается данными с сервером стороннего сервиса типа аналитики. И по какому же протоколу осуществляется обмен данными? Скорее всего HTTP(S). На момент задавания этого вопроса я разбираюсь в базах данных поверхностно, но могу предположить, что обмен данными с БД, расположенными на отдельных серверах во всяком случае иногда осуществляется тоже по протоколу HTTP.

А вот под "бэкендом", наверное, понимают всё то, что находится по ту сторону от фронтенда - тот самый чёрный ящик, который обрабатывает HTTP запросы от клиентов, но структура которого может быть заранее неизвестна для разработчиков фронтенд части. Если так, то "бэкеед" тоже не будет ответом на свой вопрос.

Ещё хотелось бы указать на путаницу, которую создают, когда говорят "Serverless application". В реальности имеют ввиду, что серверный код не придётся писать самостоятельно, а предлагается готовый сервер с проработанной логикой со стороны владельцев сервиса (поправьте меня, если я неправ).

Очень хочется воспользоваться в введённым Java словом "сервлет", но на сколько я въехал в размытые канонические определения, скорее всего, этот термин означает не то, что я имею ввиду. Ещё этот элемент, будучи принимающим разные запросы с клиентской стороны, немного ассоциируется с концепцией шины из электроники.

Comment: А в чем суть вопроса то, какова его прикладная цель?  А так, да, в естественных языках у слов бывает несколько значений зависящих от контекста ‍♂️

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, прикладная цель - спроектировать базовую файловую структуру в full-stack-проектах. Согласно моей задумке, будет папка "компоненты" (окончательные английские названия сейчас не важны), а в ней будут папки "клиент", "база данных", "сервис аналитики" и т. д. Также будет папка "взаимодействия", где будут прописаны данные, которые должны быть известны двум и и более компонентам (например, папка "сервлет-база данных" будет содержать имена таблиц, колонок и т. д.).

Comment: "В естественных языках у слов бывает несколько значений зависящих от контекста" - сейчас мы смотрим на веб-приложение в целом, полагая, что т. н. "бэкенд" может состоять из нескольких физических или виртуальных серверов. Это и есть актуальный для данного вопроса контекст.

Comment: Какая то у вас схема слишком простая. У нас на одном проекте например два независимых бакэнда. Один классический API, второй обеспечивает серверную предсборку страниц клиентского приложения. Вот и называем их просто api-сервер и "ну тот бек который для приложения". Если для этого всего зверинца пытаться придумать красивые названия, то времени работать не останется :) И кстати никакой "базовой файловой структуры" нет и быть не может. 5 отдельных проектов в гите, со своими структурами папок

Comment: @Mike, "Какая то у вас схема слишком простая." - надо же что-то взять за основу. "5 отдельных проектов в гите, со своими структурами папок" - а Вы каждому проекту по-отдельности объясняете, сколько, например, в сущности User должно быть максимум символов?

Comment: @БоковГлеб Ну всем явно ни к чему, два из них базовые образы на основе которых потом образы приложения собираются, так что там никаких прикладных сущностей. А вот с web-приложением и мобильным приложением есть места где похожие ограничения повторяются. Что то конечно API отдает, вроде точности округления. Но поля и маски ввода все таки отдельно в каждом приложении, слабо представляю как бы можно было описать это в едином месте

Comment: @Mike Благодарю Вас за то, что поделились опытом. Ладно, ввиду того, что длительные обсуждения на Stack Overflow не приветствуются, не будем спорить насчёт того, какая архитектура лучше, так как цель вопроса - уяснить, как называется часть логики, отвечающая за обработку HTTP-запросов от клиента (включая извлечение данных из источников и её выдачу в виде HTTP-ответа). Среди уже существующих терминов я пока ничего не нашёл, а сам пока придумал название "приёмная" (reception) по аналогии с тем, как в учреждениях существуют определённые места для контактов с посетителями.

Comment: @БоковГлеб А у вас http встречает само приложение ? Обычно там еще классический веб-сервер или вы его не рассматриваете, он у вас как невидимая прослойка ? у нас балансер нагрузки, он же делит на какой из беков передавать запрос, потом в pod api-сервера свои nginx, у которых в конфигах то же есть некоторая часть логики (ну она файлов которые можно было бы назвать статическими и аплоада касается) а потом уже собственно api-сервер. И лично я предпочитаю его называть api-сервером, что бы от самого nginx отличать

Comment: Короче идея в том, что общепринятых названий для этого просто не существует, так что дать "Объективный ответ, не основанный на мнениях" невозможно

Comment: @Mike, к сожалению, не совсем понял Вашего вопроса, но интуиция мне подсказывает, что ответ положительный, потому что вся серверная часть у меня на NodeJS, и есть никаких Апачей и NGix-ов нет. Что касается балансеров нагрузки, то подобные элементы я буду добавлять по мере развития инфраструктуры.

Comment: "Короче идея в том, что общепринятых названий для этого просто не существует" - Ну что ж, это то же ответ на мой вопрос. Значит, я оставляю за собой право назвать этот элемент по своему усмотрению, а  в будущем - документировать это.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что такие сервера называют front-серверами. То есть сервер, который является точкой входа запроса. Он обрабатывает HTTP-запрос и передает на внутренние серверы, которые уже можно назвать полноценным бекендом, на них реализована бизнес-логика.

Ссылка на источник, из которого я сделал такой вывод: [FAQ по архитектуре и работе ВКонтакте](https://habr.com/ru/company/oleg-bunin/blog/449254/#:%7E:text=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B.-,Front%2D%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80,-Front%2D%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82)

Comment: Уважаемый Давид! С великим удовольствием оцениваю Ваш ответ и награждаю Вас очками репутации! Очень лаконичный ответ с авторитетным источником данных.

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от функционала данного звена в цепи. На мой взгляд - это чистый `backend` (программно-аппаратная часть сервиса). Здесь уместен вопрос из вашего взгляда: что находится по ту сторону от фронтенда? Некий API, который используют фронт, сервисы и база. Так почему это не `backend`? То есть некоторое програмное обеспечение, которое понимает запросы к API и это может быть как HTTP, HTTP(s), SQL, MQTT и еще весть знает что.

Про огранизацию `back'a` - это совершенно другой вопрос. Поскольку технологий и протоколов предостаточно, чтобы устроить холивар по этому поводу.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Прошу прощения за то, что недостаточно хорошо это передал, но мой вопрос фокусируется именно на организации backend-а. То, что по отношению в клиентской части backend- это некий чёрный ящик - это понятно. А вот если разобрать backend на базу данных (или несколько таковых), сторонние сервисы, дополнительные сервера (например для отдачи файлов), то тот элемент, о котором я спрашиваю - это что? (если какое-то более-менее устоявшееся название существует)

Comment: @БоковГлеб самое понятное в этом случае будет только тогда, когда вы опишите функционал данной части. Эта часть может не быть однокомпонентной и может содержать в себе несколько частей. Например, веб-сервер (запросы по протоколам), коннектор БД (как пример ODBC) и API интерфейсы (открытые концы для сервисов). То есть то, что у вас под знаком вопроса это бэк, вот его и можно разделить на функциональные части для понимания и масштабирования в последствии

Comment: Функционал такой: обработка HTTP-запросов, идущих напрямую от пользователей, и в рамках этого - выдача данных из своих или внешних источников (HTML-код, файлы стилей и JavaScript-скриптов, данных из базы данных и так далее). Хотя этот элемент может не иметь ярко выраженной архитектуры вообще, обычно он состоит из кода, написанного по шаблонам проектирования "единая точка входа", "роутер", "контроллер", "модель", "представление".